# Parse.com Javascript API, query List of objects that contain lists of pointers

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I need to query my Parse.com backend for a list of objects, that have a list of pointers within those objects.

Given a pointer value, how can I query for a list of objects whose inner list of pointers contains that pointer value?

Some more detail, ObjectA contains a list of pointers, to ObjectB. When I delete ObjectB, I have cloud code that cascades this deletion. I need to query all of my ObjectA's that have ObjectB in their list of ObjectB's.

I hope this makes sense.

I have been looking at the "contain" methods for the Javascript API; Do these methods also work with keys that are arrays?

My current beforeDelete implementation is as follows.

```
    var objectB = request.object;
    var objectAQuery = new Parse.Query('ObjectA');

    objectAQuery.find().then(
        function (objectAArray) {
            objectAArray.forEach(function (objectA) {
                objectA.remove('objectBListKey',objectB);
            });
            Parse.Object.saveAll(objectAArray, {
                success: function () {
                    response.success();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    response.error(error);
                }
            });
        },
        function (error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    );
```

This code seems inefficient as its querying a ton of unnecessary ObjectA's that may not even have a pointer in their list of ObjectB's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems like what you are looking for is the `containedIn` function on `Parse.Query`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_containedIn). This would allow you to query on the ObjectA class on the key of the pointer array, returning only the ObjectA instances that have the pointer you passed into the `containedIn` parameter in its array of pointers.

Comment: This was it, i had something wrong with my logic when i used this. Once corrected it started to work! thank you.